# Add context menu entry to foreign program

Tags: java, runtime, reverse-engineering, binaryfiles

I would like to write an extension E for an open source program P, which is not written in the language in which I would write the extension and which I have to use (Java). Is there some standard procedure (how) to add a context menu entry to a running binary (P) using the input from a text field in P as input to my extension E? (e.g. as a command line argument)? (I am thinking of a sort of runtime patching.)

P is written by one person, which uses solely a rather different programming language and my extension is of really small interest to other users (solving a domain-specific problem for colleagues), so I do not consider it wise to bother the developer or having the burden to maintain a fork, which would have to be manually revisited every time the program is updated, even if there are only invisible changes under the hood. Or are my conclusions wrong?

Comment: In general this does not seem like a feasible approach. An actual "context menu entry" (I assume you mean when right clicking something in the open source program) should be implemented inside said software. You can then from there call your Java program with whatever arguments you want.

Could you disclose what open source program you are looking at? That would make it easier to judge

Comment: Thanks. The open source program is HeidiSQL, writtten in Pascal.